# Place after content below its parent element

Tags: html, css

I want the content placed in `page:after` to go underneath the `page`. I used negative *z-index*, but nothing changed. In the below *plunker*, the lines between the icons should go below each icon. Could someone help me?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VtbA5uitCqSi59mbxRxr?p=preview)

```css
body{
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.pages{
  width: 100%;
}
.page{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.page:after{
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: -50%;
  z-index:-1;
}
.page:first-child:after{
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="pages">
  <li class="page">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="page">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="page">
    <i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you need to set icon in position:relative; and eventually add z-index if needed: https://plnkr.co/edit/B9w2HRN5wBv7TpQOcDEi?p=preview added a different color to make it obvious

Comment: No matter how many times I look at it, it's below it.

Comment: http://imgur.com/wP0JJEH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of placing `:after` on `.page`, place it on `.fa` (the icons).

Changes:

```
 .page {
    left: 2px;
  }

  .fa:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    top: 50%;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
  }
```

#### SNIPPET

```css
.pages {
  width: 100%;
}
.page {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  left: 2px;
}
.fa:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  top: 50%;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="pages">
  <li class="page">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="page">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="page">
    <i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the top to `top: 1.5em;`

```css
.pages {
  width: 100%;
}
.page {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.page:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;
  left: -50%;
}
.page:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link data-require="font-awesome@*" data-semver="4.5.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<div>
  <ul class="pages">
    <li class="page">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="page">
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="page">
      <i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
i {background: white;}
```

this solved the problem

Comment: This doesn't even affect anything

Comment: Actually, according to other comments, it was below. so problem is with the look

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality content on Stack Overflow. Please add some description about why this answers the question.